# Rails: Using .build in a rake task to create child objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm attempting to run a rake task that will create parent objects and then child objects off of the parent ones. However, the ".build" doesn't seem to be working. Could this be because the rake task is not inheriting the association?

```
parentType = ParentType.create(name: "new parent")
childTypes = ["test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]

childTypes.each_with_index do |childType,index|
   parentType.child_types.build(name: childType, parent_type_id: parentType.id)
end
```

Comment: `build` is not saving new object to the database, try `create` instead.

Comment: Create does work fine but I'm wondering why build works when running the same method in a controller but not in a rake task.

Comment: Oh, I just realized--I'm not saving the parent object and hence not the child object. Makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

create a task in lib and then create the parent first and then the child
**in lib/tasks/create_children.rake**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

namespace :create do
  desc "Rake task to create parents and its childrens" 
  #####execute using  bundle exec rake create:create_children --trace
  task :create_children=> :environment do

   @user1=User.create!(email: "testuser_1@test.com",password:"qqqqqq",first_name: "user1", last_name: "user1", username: "user1")
   #user has_many categories
   @user1.categories.create!(:category_id=>rand(1..100)) 
   #user has_many images
   @user1.images.create!({:avatar => File.new("#{Rails.root}/public/images/sample.jpg")})

  end
end
```

**you must enter valid values to save the records.**